# How I can add event listener to XMLHttpRequest in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native.

I tried a lot of ways to upload a file to server and handle progress.
I found that using XMLHttpRequest can achieve this, but when I try to use

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('progress',function(event){....});
```

for the first time this code has worked, but after reloading js this code did not work any more and a strange error occurred:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'request.addEventListener')

What is the problem and how this can be solved?

React is really very strange, something works today and doesn't work tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the `componentWillMount` method is not run when just reloading the Javascript and not restarting the application. This was a problem for me when i tried to catch an event sent over the react bridge. If you are using this to start the listener it will not be added if you just reload the JavaScript. I simply restart the application every time I changed something and have to test if the code is catching the event.

I have done this on an android device and it worked. Hope this helps you. I will come back if I find an actual solution to the problem and not just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need this anymore but for others this is the correct way to add an event listener:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) { console.log(event); });
```